# Find $a$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos(\sqrt{ax})}{x^2}=3$.

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Find $a$ such that
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos(\sqrt{ax})}{x^2}=3.$$ Can we solve it with l'Hospital's Rule or do we need to use Taylor series?

I have tried using L'Hospital's Rule and i keep getting $\frac{0}{0}$.

from the taylor series expansion i get $$f(x)=1-cos(\sqrt{ax})=1-(1-\frac{a x}{2}+\frac{a^2 x^2}{24}-\frac{a^3 x^3}{720}+\frac{a^4 x^4}{40320})$$ and $g(x)=x^2$ so, $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-(1-\frac{a x}{2}+\frac{a^2 x^2}{24}-\frac{a^3 x^3}{720}+\frac{a^4 x^4}{40320})}{x^2}$$ $$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\frac{a (a^3 x^3-42 a^2 x^2+840 a x-5040)}{10080}}{2x}$$ $$=\lim_{x\to0}-\frac{a (a^3 x^3-42 a^2 x^2+840 a x-5040)}{20160x}$$ $$=\frac{5040a}{0}$$
which in my opinion proves that the question is wrong! What is your opinion on this?
Note: Btw I am not related with those negative votes to answers.

Comment: Your question is not complete.

Comment: Taylor series will quickly tell you what's going on. Presumably you want the limit to exist. Not many $a$!

Comment: Ahh i forgot to add 3 as the limit i edited the question.

Comment: Are you sure of the question? It is over $x$ or $x^2$?

Comment: As Mhenni points out his suspicion, in order for limit to exist we must have $x$ in denominator or better $a = 0$ in which case limit is $0$.

Comment: if it is $x^2$ , then I am sorry to say the question is wrong and the limit doesn't exist !

Comment: @user102867: But with $x^{2}$ in denominator the limit does not exist. must be a typo in the book.

Comment: Can we use L'Hopital's Rule to find a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use L'Hopital again on $f'(x)/g'(x)$ as it is $0/0$. Therefore the limit will be the same as $f''(x)/g''(x)$. Differentiating numerator and denominator gives $a\sin(\sqrt a*x))/2=3$. Then multiplying through by 2 gives $a*\sin(\sqrt a*x)=6$. At the limit of $x=0$, $a=6$.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider the Taylor series for $1 - \cos\left(\sqrt{ax}\right)$, you have
$$\frac{a x}2 - \frac{a^2 x^2}{24} + \frac{a^3 x^3}{720}.$$
Dividing by $x^2$ shows that the limit does not exist.

Comment: limit is actually 3 so it exists.?.

Comment: Why a downvote ?

Comment: Its not from me someone else downvotes I only have 8 reputation.

Comment: this is really weird. One should disable the "downvote without comment" feature on stackexchange...

Comment: @ParamanandSingh. I totally agree with you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:  Use $$\cos2A=1-2\sin^2A$$ and $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin h}h=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Write the expansion of $\cos(t)$. Let $t = \sqrt{ax}$. You will see that the limit does not exist.

$$\cos(t) = 1-\frac{t^2}{2!} + \frac{t^4}{4!}-\cdots$$

Comment: What the hell man , the answer is correct !

Comment: Normally a downvote should be accompanied by a comment. Please let us know what is wrong with this answer.

Comment: someone is trolling i suppose he negs all answers.

Comment: oops too bad. Moderators please help us!!

Comment: Moderator. Mayday Mayday Mayday Mayday